# How to parse a variables to subprocess.run in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am new to python. I have install.py. Below are the variables stored its values. When execute/run abc.py, it's unable to copy the file from remote to local server. When samething is hardcoded values in subprocess commands, able to transfer file, but passing variable in subprocess not working. Referred other articles, but no luck.

```
srcuser=abcd srcip=x.x.x.x srcpath=/home/sum/mnt/ sshprkey=/home/xyz/id_rsa
subprocess.run(['sudo', 'scp', '-P22', '-i sshprkey', 'srcuser@srcip:srcpath/"mongodb-org-3.6.repo"', '/etc/yum.repos.d/'])
```

Thanks

Comment: Its a shell built in command. you need to tell subprocess that it is a shell command. see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this we assign shell keyword argument to true.

```
subprocess.run(['sudo', 'scp', '-P22', '-i sshprkey', 'srcuser@srcip:srcpath/"mongodb-org-3.6.repo"', '/etc/yum.repos.d/'], shell=True)
```

Using Popen (copying from python docs)
On Unix with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh. If args is a string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell. This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be when typed at the shell prompt. This includes, for example, quoting or backslash escaping filenames with spaces in them. If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself.

#### You need to make sure that the first first item specifies the command string

```
Popen(['sudo scp', '-P22', '-i sshprkey', 'srcuser@srcip:srcpath/"mongodb-org-3.6.repo"', '/etc/yum.repos.d/'],shell=True)
```

Comment: it displays scp usage syntax and unable to copy the file. subprocess.Popen(['scp', '-P22', '-i sshprkey', 'srcuser@srcip:srcpath/srcfilename', '/etc/yum.repos.d/'],shell=True). Also tried with sudo as per above statement, same scp usage syntax is displayed

Comment: dear sir (@Ganesh) - i wrote you enough and useful data (quoting py docs). please do the rest. go to py docs here [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) and read the subprocess module. 
Thats better for you.!